# How can I remove "(?) " from a variable in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some code that will look a the contents of a variable and remove "(?) " if it is in the variable. The "?" could be any number, but I want to remove the parentheses, the content between them, and the space after.

Comment: You want to remove a literal `(` followed by a number and then a literal `)`?

Comment: You would hopefully write some code to accomplish your task. what have you written so far?

Comment: right, I gave an answer, because I'm a sucker for the points and the badges, but I agree that this one is easy (or at least google-able) enough where you could have taken a wack at it

Comment: Many programming questions are 'google-able' because Google finds answers here. Regardless how easy the question is, provide a good and solid answer. If you don't want to, you're free to only answer more difficult questions.

Comment: Thanks guys sorry I didn't provide a code sample. I thought I had. I guess I forgot to paste it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a jQuery issue, but rather a JavaScript issue. Here's one solution:

```javascript
'23(56) 234'.replace(/\(\d+\)\s?/g, '');
```

This results in `23234`, since we matched a `(`, followed by a digit repeated (`\d+`), followed by another `)`, followed by an optional space (`\s`). The second parameter shows that we're replacing this matched pattern with nothing (`''`).

Answer (score 5):

```
str = str.replace(/\(\d+\)\w/g, "");
```

and if you want decimals too:

```
str = str.replace(/\(\d+\.\d+\)\w/g, "");
```

Comment: 'and the space after' :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks! I forgot about that bit

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `replace` method:

```
'foo(1)'.replace(/\(\d\)/, '')
```

outputs 'foo'

Comment: I interpreted his 'any number' as 'any digit', but you may very well be right